# Complex-ish query in Laravel (Eloquent)

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I've read the Laravel documentation but I can't quite work this one out.

Does anyone know if this query is possible in Eloquent?

If so, how would you write it?

```
SELECT 

MONTHNAME(postdate) as monthname, 
DATE_FORMAT(postdate,'%m') as month, 
YEAR(postdate) as year, 
COUNT(MONTHNAME(postdate)) as num 

FROM 
postData 

WHERE 
status = 1 

GROUP BY 
monthname,
year 

ORDER BY 
postdate DESC
```

Comment: Is there a reason for not just using DB::raw() or selectRaw() for this one?? just curious

Comment: @KyleK I'd guess that if he's asking such question without mentioning it's probably because he doesn't know of `DB::raw` or `selectRaw`.

Comment: Well yeah...I wasn't sure, because he specifically put (Eloquent) in brackets, so I thought maybe he specifically wants an eloquent/fluent version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While simply using `DB::raw` for the whole query does work, it doesn't feel right to me. You might wanna try this solution using the Query Builder.

```
DB::table('postData')->select([
    DB::raw('MONTHNAME(postdate) AS monthname'),
    DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(postdate, \'%m\') AS month'),
    DB::raw('YEAR(postdate) AS year'),
    DB::raw('COUNT(MONTHNAME(postdate)) AS num'),
])->where('status', 1)
  ->groupBy('monthname', 'year')
  ->orderBy('postdate', 'DESC');
```

It still uses `DB::raw`, but only for the select clause. Anyway, you could have used a `PostData` model instead of `DB::table('postData')`, but since it really wouldn't be a regular `PostData` object, I'd advise against it.

Comment: This is what I was after.  Thanks.  Can I ask what you mean by the PostData object?  My intention was to start the query like this: $posts = $this->posts->select([...

Comment: Oh, you're accessing as relation through another model. You see, whenever I have a Model, I'd expect it to have all fields the table it's mapped to does. So, if I you returned `PostData` I'd expect it to have a `postdate` and `status` property, instead of the custom ones you specified using the AS clauses.

PS: If you're really using it as a relationship, remember you actually gotta do `$this->posts()->select(...`. Notice `posts()` instead of `posts`. This is due to how Laravel handles the magic properties.

Comment: Thanks Raphael.  I appreciate the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using DB::raw() just do this...

Easy copy...

DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT MONTHNAME(postdate) as monthname, DATE_FORMAT(postdate,'%m') as month, 
YEAR(postdate) as year, COUNT(MONTHNAME(postdate)) as num FROM postData WHERE status = 1 GROUP BY 
monthname,year ORDER BY postdate DESC"));

One line...

```
  DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT MONTHNAME(postdate) as monthname, DATE_FORMAT(postdate,'%m') as month,YEAR(postdate) as year, COUNT(MONTHNAME(postdate)) as num FROM postData WHERE status = 1 GROUP BYmonthname,year ORDER BY postdate DESC"));
```

Comment: Forgot to add `"` around the query.

Comment: Thanks KyleK. Yeah, I didn't know how to use DB::raw correctly.